# Python class read only variable without '_' at beginning of the name

Tags: python

Hi I have a class representing or local calendar(other than **AD**)
Here I want all those class attributes to be **read only**

```
class BSDate(object):

def __init__(self, year, month, date):
    self._year = year
    self._month = month
    self._date = date
```

In Python interpretor, I want to get month so I have to do like this:

```
x = BSDate(2072,5,2)
x._month
```

but I want to get month by simply calling

```
x.month
```

How can I solve this.

Comment: [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [@property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) to emulate a getter method

```
@property
def year(self):
    return self._year

@property
def month(self):
    return self._month

@property
def date(self):
    return self._date
```

Now when your client code can be:

```
my_date = BSDate(y, m, d)
month = my_date.month
year = my_date.year
date = my_date.date
```

`@property` can also be used to enforce "read only" values:

```
@property.setter
def month(self, value):
    raise AttributeError("This value is read only")
```

The code will raise an error if the client tries to modify `month`

Comment: You should show the error when the property is tried to be written to, prove it is read only, also a link to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) would be nice.

Comment: Also I can set the value by **x._month = 2**. I assume **_month** should be protected.

Comment: Good points TMDJ, I amended my answer to add your suggestions.

Comment: @wrufesh You cannot enforce readonly like you can in C' or Java. The _ or __ convention is that: a convention. If your consumer decides he HAS TO modify the variable, he can. But _/__ is a strongly urge for him to not do that.

Answer (score 4):

```
class BSDate(object):
    def __init__(self, year, month, date):
        self._year = year
        self._month = month
        self._date = date

    @property
    def month(self):
        return self._month
```

You can leave it at that as you can now use `obj.month` to access it and it raises `AttributeError` if someone tries `obj.month = val`. However, if you want to inform the user about this behaviour at run time and/or more informative about the error message implement the corresponding setter as follows.

```
    @property.setter
    def month(self, value):
        # self._month = value if you want to set
        raise AttributeError("Very good error message")
        # or just print to terminal that can't set and go ahead
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python you should not really worry about private properties, the recommended practice is to simply use attributes and use properties only when you need to enforce constraints on assignments or calculated values.
Python's philosophy is that "we are all consenting adults" and one should not make things more complicated than they need to be. I would simply use attributes until you have a strong reason to use something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in python to do a true read-only property. You can however, as others have mentioned declare a function with a `property` decorator. You could also overload the setter function by `def __setattr__(self, key, value):`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why instance variables start with an underscore is to remind programmers that it is poor practice to ever call them outside their class. However, you can always add an accessor/getter method to your class:

```
def month(self):
    return(self._month)
```

This way you can simply call

```
x.month()
```

to get the month associated with `x`.